# multi-platform image building not supported when pushing to Docker engine

Tags: quarkus

(1)settings in application.properties:

quarkus.jib.platforms=linux/amd64,linux/arm64/v8

(2)then exec:

clean package -DskipTests -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true

(3)with result:

multi-platform image building not supported when pushing to Docker engine

how to solve this problem?